# How to make excel run a fonction made with substitute and concatenate and calculate the number value

Tags: excel, graph, command, string-concatenation, string-substitution

I want to make a graph in excel. So in one cell, i type the formula. (Let's say Sin(x). Then Somewhere else, i made a table of x values and y values. The x values goes from -5 to 5 with a step size of 0,01. I used substitute in the y column to replace "x" by the value of x next to it. (let's says it become Sin(5). Now i want excel to calculate sin(5). I tried concatenate it with "=" but it's counted as string. I tried the indirect fonction, it didn't work, it gave a ref#, i tried to see the calculation step and it failed on the first step.  I tried the value fonction, it didn't work, got a #value. I know that if i carefully copy and paste with values only, then press F2 and hit enter, its gonna calculate. But i don't want to do it manually.

Thats made with the x+2 fonction, whats on the left does itself automatically but it's seen as a string of text by excel, not a function:

[image]

Same thing but with sin(x) +1:

[image]

A simplified version with two examples. What's written in each cell is written below in between quotation mark.""

[image]

It's to give an idea of what i'm trying to do. There's the y column made a substitution of F6. I'd want another column, or this column to show the number value rather then text (this one is kinda useless, the first 3 are better to explain my point).

[image]

That's just to see the commands (this one is kinda useless, the first 3 are better to explain my point).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  I'm having trouble following what you're trying to do (and *why*). Perhaps if you gave a single start-to-finish example, it would make more sense Show what you have, what you want to have when finished, what you've tried, and why it's not working. See [mcve]. Also screenshots are easier to understand if they are cropped to only include an example, not the entire screen.

Comment: I have a command(A mathematical fonction) made with the substitute fonction. This command counts as Text (-5+2), i want excel to view it as if i clicked on the cells and wrote (=-5+2) then press enter (it would calculate -5+2 and the cell value would be -3). In one cell i wrote the fonction (x+2) then i want to substitute x by its value in the table. So in the y colum i have =SUBSTITUTE($F$7,"x",$J6) which is -5+2 then below it i have =SUBSTITUTE($F$7,"x",$J7) which is -4.99 +2 ... The endgoal is to write a fonction like sin(x) + x -log(x) in ONE cell and for other cell to use this fonction.

Comment: but they substitute x by the numerical value of x(in the cell to its left) and then to actually calculate the result/numerical value. So i can make a software a bit like desmos but in excel. The only thing i need. THE IMPORTANT PART is: How to transform "-5+2" in a cell from a STRING OF TEXT to an EXCEL FONCTION. This would work with other excel fonction, not only mathematical.

Comment: -5+2 is an exemple. This would allow to write any excel fonction in one place, except it would replace the cell reference by "x". And then a table calling this fonction would replace the "x" by the corresponding cell.

Comment: You can use vba to translate a string to a formula. But maybe there's a better way to solve your real problem.

Comment: It's ok if the solution works with VBA Scripts. It doesn't have to work on excel alone. Maybe something that copy the String Value in another case and then update it would work. I don't care about having helper cell too. So how would i do it? I only know a handfull of commands in VBA.